# Confusion about the kind of offset-value for this non homogenous poisson-process

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, poisson-process, offset

Suppose that I observe $M$-times this kind of table:

```
     t X
 1:  1 0
 2:  2 0
 3:  3 0
 4:  4 0
 5:  5 0
 6:  6 1
 7:  7 0
 8:  8 0
 9:  9 0
10: 10 0
11: 11 0
12: 12 0
13: 13 0
14: 14 0
15: 15 0
16: 16 5
17: 17 1
18: 18 0
19: 19 0
20: 20 0
.   . .
.   . .
T-1:T-1 0
T:  T 0
```

So, what I get is like: $x_1 = 0, x_2 = 0, x_3 = 0, x_4 = 0, x_5 = 0, x_6 = 1....$, i.e., $X_t \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,...\}$ where $t = 0,1,2,...,T-1,T$. As we can see, I observe jumps greater then one for particular $t$'s (like $t = 16, \rightarrow x_{16} = 5$).

**I want to investigate if more counts occur if $t$ moves towards $T$ and what the impacts of different covariates, captured in $\boldsymbol{X}$, are.**

To do that, I could assume that $N(t) = \sum_{i=1}^t X_t$ is a poisson-process, i.e.,

(1) $P(N(t) = k) = \frac{\lambda(t)t^{k}}{k!}\text{exp}\{-\lambda(t)t\}$

The regression model will be:

(2) $\text{log}\{E(N(t)|t)\} = \boldsymbol{X\beta + \epsilon}$

$\Leftrightarrow \text{log}\{\lambda(t)t\} = \boldsymbol{X\beta + \epsilon}$

$\Leftrightarrow \text{log}\{\lambda(t)\} = -\text{log}\{t\} + \boldsymbol{X\beta + \epsilon}$

In this case, I would model $-\text{log}\{t\}$ as the *offset-value* and take $N(t)$ as the dependend variable - which is just the cumsum of $X_i$, where $i$ goes from $1$ to $T$.

**Question 1:**
*I think here I'll get a problem because, as far as I remember, for particular $t$'s, the process is not supposed to jump by more then one?*

Another way I could think of, is, that I see my data as a big cross-table. If I assume that each cell count is a realization of an independent poisson-process and the total count $n$ is fixed, then I'm able to say that I observe a set of counts $n_1,...,n_T$ which are each poissonian with rate $\lambda_t$.

If these assumptions hold, it can be shown that the cell counts are Multinomial$(\frac{\lambda_t}{n_1},...,\frac{\lambda_t}{n_T},n)$.

Hence, if I see the observations as a multinomial respones, for the cell counts $X_t$, I'll get the model:

(3) $\text{log}\{E(X_t)\}) = \boldsymbol{X\beta + \epsilon}$

$\Leftrightarrow \text{log}\{\lambda_t\} = \boldsymbol{X\beta + \epsilon}$

$\Leftrightarrow \text{log}\{np_t\} = \boldsymbol{X\beta + \epsilon}$

$\Leftrightarrow \text{log}\{p_t\} = -\text{log}\{n\} + \boldsymbol{X\beta + \epsilon}$

**Question 2:**
*Now, I would choose $-\text{log}\{n\}$ as my offset-value. If the sequence of $\lambda_t, \ \ t = 1,...,T$ is increasing in $t$, this would answer my question. Since my $n$ is actually fixed and with this approach I'm able to deal with the multiple jumps at some $t$ it seems that the model (3) would be the way to go?*

**Question 3:**
*If I use a `glm()` what would my dependend variable be? I thought about defining a new r.v. $Y_t$ which is 1 if $X_t>0$ and zero otherwise. If $X_t>1$ then I would duplicate the corresponding row $x_t$-times. If I do that, in my optinion, things are not supposed to change since I look at a ratio as a dependend variable anyway?*

**Question 4:**
*Another issue I've is, that in model (2) I'm not sure how (3) catches that moving towards $T$ the cumsum of $X_t$ inceases steadily, since (3) looks at each cell separately.*